# Retrieving body of json Object of an http Request C#

Tags: c#, json, httprequest, body-parser

I have the problem, that I can't retrieve the body of a POST statement of a JSON Object. Here is the function, which is called when executing the http-Request:

```
        public static HttpResponseMessage Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = "HttpTriggerCSharp/name/{name}")]HttpRequestMessage req, string name, TraceWriter log)
    {
        log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(req.Content.ToString());

        // Fetching the name from the path parameter in the request URL
        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, output);

    }
```

Im executing the POST with Postman and the following URL: http://localhost:7071/api/HttpTriggerCSharp/name/test

In the Header I wrote "Content-Type: application/json" and the Body looks like this:

```
  {  
   "Benutzer":"Nenad",
   "Passwort":"test"
  }
```

My result is this: "\"System.Net.Http.StreamContent\""

Thank you for your help!

Comment: i think you should use `httpResponse.Content.ReadAsString();`

Comment: You have to first read your stream into a string of give the stream directly to the serializer

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the answers guys,

i found now an other solution with the help of a friend, this is the following:

```
        public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = "HttpTriggerCSharp/name/{name}")]HttpRequestMessage req, string name, TraceWriter log)
    {
        log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        dynamic dataArray = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();

        string output = dataArray.ToString();

        var data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Benutzer>(output);

        // Fetching the name from the path parameter in the request URL
        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, data);

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Content is an instance of [HttpContent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.http.httpcontent(v=vs.118).aspx) class (as you can see in your output). So you have to use an appropriate method to get the string.